# Resetting outputted HTML markup to default?

Tags: theming

I am trying to fix a site, which I did not build nor 'break'.

On a clean install of Drupal, the markup for a node's textfield, set to display inline, looks like this:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-foo field-type-text field-label-inline clearfix">
  <div class="field-label">Foo:&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On my problem site it looks liike this:

```
<span class="field-label">Foo: </span>
<div class="field field-name-field-foo field-type-text field-label-inline inline">Bar</div>
```

I have turned off the custom theme and I have disabled the Display Suite module, cleared all caches - no change.

Are there any other obvious places I could look to find what is changing the outputted markup?

There are 250 modules enabled, so turning things off one by one is not really an option.

Thanks.

Comment: See if they have a module called fences

Comment: If they do have fences installed you can edit the field and change the wrapper markup to 'Default'; it should go back to normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was the configuration of the fences module. I needed to cancel the override in the first section. Navigate to Fences configuration to change the settings.

[image]